# stachow to run vba across a column of values to return a value to another column?

Tags: excel, timezone-offset, vba

I am trying to put Low for a split second in column D in the corresponding row to every instance of 0 within column E.

My problem is my code only references the first instance of 0 **contained in F3** and not the second. 
How would I adjust this formula to reference the second 0 and put a `"LOW"` for a very small amount if time in D7 and then `"high"`

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub pump_on88()
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set Rng = Range("E1:E50").Find(What:="0", LookAt:=xlWhole,    LookIn:=xlValues)
        Rng.Offset(, -1).Value = "LOW"
        Sleep (1)
        Rng.Offset(, -1).Value = "high"
    End With
End Sub
```

for the above formula I get below without a high in F7:

```
 D   E  RUNNING SUBgave    D   E  F    G
     3                         3     vba macro button for sub of no. in F1 
     4                         4  0  vba macro button for sub of no. in F2
     0                    high 0     vba macro button for sub of no. in F3
     3                         3     vba macro button for sub of no. in F4
     2                         2     vba macro button for sub of no. in F5
     3                         3     vba macro button for sub of no. in F6
     0                         0     vba macro button for sub of no. in F7
```

missing out the last 0

Below works except I get the error about constant expression for the reference to 0. **i.e I need it referenced as a cell ie `F3` so that I can create 7 subs and make buttons for them as in the above example in column G showing this.** . See error below

```
Sub Test()
Dim Rng As Range, firstAddress As String
Const strFindMe As String = "0"

With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E50")
    Set Rng = .Find(what:=strFindMe, LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = Rng.Address
        Do
            Rng.Offset(, -1).Value = "LOW"
            Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
        Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

for `"0"` and when I use `worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3")` I get  `'constant expression required'` error

**I have researched and found that you can't use a cell reference as a constant so mrbungles code will need to be changed to cater for this**

Comment: You need some **FindNext** code.

Comment: Thanks Gary - sounds good. I'll do a bit of research then - naturally. Do you think it would be best with a loop of some kind?

Comment: **YES**.......................be careful to terminate the loop properly.

Comment: @Jonmark Give it a try and post back with any issues.

Comment: @mrbungle had a good solution but I need a to refer the cell F3 containing the 0 but I can't refer cells as constants :(

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Rng As Range, firstAddress As String
    Const strFindMe As String = "0"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E50")
        Set Rng = .Find(what:=strFindMe, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Rng.Offset(, -1).Value = "LOW"
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks mrbungle it works but when I tested this replacing "0" with Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3") I got constant expression required as an error - can we get it to work with a cell reference ? sorry I should have had this in the original question - it was slightly vague

Comment: my research tells me you can't have a cell reference as a constant :S

Comment: what should the final result look like?

Comment: hi mrbungle well it should basically be the same as your code because it works but being able to reference the 0 in cell F3 instead of the 0 directly. So it will look the same except that a cell will be referencing 0 instead of 0 being referenced directly.

Comment: the reason I will need a cell reference is because I can then put a vba macro button to perform the sub in adjacent other columns alongside F3 for example in column G. In this case when F3 changes the function would perform the loop. I could then put a vba macro button in every cell in the adjacent column eg column G downwards to have this effect of running the sub or subs at my will to quickly put quickly in every cell in column D contained the relative reference in E a LOW that quickly turns to a high

Comment: I updated the question slightly to show what I'm trying to achieve. Basically I just need to be able to use the cell reference  instead of "0" so I can make 7 subs of your sub to put in each cell of column G to reference the adjacent F columns value.

Comment: You were so close I though you had it... Instead of defining a `const`, try `Dim strFindMe As String     strFindMe = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F3").Value`

Comment: Sorry I was delayed getting back but it worked brilliantly on Mar 6- thankyou Porcupine911 and mr bungle :)